# Can I use Angular inject function when extending Spartacus components/services?

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

When I'm extending Spartacus component or service, and I want to add a new dependency via DI (Dependency Injection), I have to extend the original constructor and pass all it's dependencies. Is there a simpler way to do it? e.g. with the new Angular's `inject()` function?

For example, the default Spartacus class is:

```
export class CmsPageGuard {
  constructor(
    protected routingService: RoutingService,
    protected cmsService: CmsService,
    protected protectedRoutesGuard: ProtectedRoutesGuard,
    protected service: CmsPageGuardService,
    protected routingConfig: RoutingConfigService
  ) {}

  /*...*/
```

And when I want to add a new dependency, e.g. WindowRef, I have to repeat all the original dependencies and add the new one in the end:

```
export class CustomCmsPageGuard extends CmsPageGuard {
  constructor(
    protected routingService: RoutingService,
    protected cmsService: CmsService,
    protected protectedRoutesGuard: ProtectedRoutesGuard,
    protected service: CmsPageGuardService,
    protected routingConfig: RoutingConfigService,
    protected windowRef: WindowRef // MY NEW USED DEPENDENCY
  ) {
    super(
      routingService,
      cmsService,
      protectedRoutesGuard,
      service,
      routingConfig
    );
  }

  someCustomLogicExampleUsingNewDependency() {
    if(this.windowRef.isBrowser()) 
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a simpler way since Angular 14 the new [inject](https://angular.io/api/core/inject) function was introduced and now you can use it to inject your new dependencies without the need to touch the original constructor. Here's the example:

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';

/* ... */

export class CustomCmsPageGuard extends CmsPageGuard {
  protected windowRef = inject(WindowRef);

  someCustomLogicExampleUsingNewDependency() {
    if(this.windowRef.isBrowser()) {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you suggest this methode with inject also for the case, if i only need one dependency of the already used ones?

For example, i just need the `cmsService`?

Comment: Hi @andreasbecker.de good to hear from you. If the original dependency (or any property) is marked as `protected` in the _parent class_, then your child class will simpli inherit this property and you should be good to _just use it_ as `this.cmsService` for example in your child (inheriting) class. No additional effort, no need for a custom constructor or custom inject(). We try to expose ~100% of properties in Spartacus as protected or public for easy extensibility. But if you find some property private and you have good extensibility usecase, please create a feature request / support ticket